# Webpack: How to make an "extensions" API with bundles transpiled after-the-fact?

Tags: webpack, requirejs

We're creating a dashboard implementation. We want to use Webpack to build the core dashboard code and a set of standard widget implementations and want to make it possible for others to make their own widget implementations that implement a "Dashboard Widget API" and integrate with the dashboard.

In a Webpack environment, how do we allow extension authors to take advantage of the `import`s already present in core *without requiring all extensions to be available when core gets built*?

If I think of bundle files as sort of `.so` shared libraries, how do I create the javascript equivalent of `.so` files that allow extension authors to "link" against them to create extensions that use dependenceies and APIs in "the `.so`"?

In our old RequireJS dashboard implementation that this is replacing, each widget was `require`d and they in turn would load their own requirements. Worked great. It allowed for:

- A core build that provides several APIs available to both core and extensions via RequireJS's `require`.
- Requirements such as `lodash` were only loaded once and shared between core and extensions.
- Extensions could be written and tested *independently of the core*.

  - Could be written after the core had been installed on a server
  - A core update didn't require changing the extensions at all, as long as the API remained stable.

Now that we're using Webpack, how can this be accomplished?

Of course we could just define an API and let each extension run webpack by themselves, and then use RequireJS to load them. Tried that. But now dependencies are not shared. Loading [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) and Vue and not doing much else gives a bundle of 427KB. Multiplied by 20 widget types, this is not ideal...

Comment: First order of business could be to define a vendor chunk:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#split-chunks-example-3

Comment: Also - the extensions could omit the dependencies like lodash in their webpack  build: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/